# No camera / media stream when React Native apk is installed on physical device without cable

Tags: javascript, react-native, getusermedia

The Android React Native app I'm building accesses the camera / media stream via `getUserMedia`. When I run the app on my `adb` physical device using `react-native run-android` and a cable, I can see the stream captured by the video camera perfectly when I navigate to the Scene that uses it.

However, when I create an apk using:

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`

`cd android/
./gradlew assembleDebug`

and install on the device, sending the apk via slack to the phone, the media stream does not appear in the component when I navigate to it! Obviously I can't de-bug the app. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have permissions for camera api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered the reason - for some reason, when it's built the latter way in my description the device needs storage permissions! :/